# Usage of past continues tense in describing evidences

Tags: tense, past-continuous, continuous

I wrote the following sentence to describe my evidence of how some users used a system.

> They first showed difficulties in discriminating phonemes, especially short vowels, as they frequently requested to listen the word again.

In Persian we have a special continues past tense for such sentences as they were doing somethings when we were observing. It seems the English doesn't have such tense or maybe I can use past continues like "*they first were showing ... as they were requesting ....*"?

Comment: "At first they showed difficulties ..."

Comment: I think it is OK to say "They first *were showing* difficulties in discriminating phonemes, especially short vowels, as they frequently requested to listen ***to*** the word again."? Though I have to agree with @AdrianHHH that "At first they..." sounds better (assuming that you go on to say what happened next).

Comment: "They first *were showing* ..." sounds weird to me.

Comment: @user3169 I even thought "*At first, they **showed** difficulties .... as they frequently **were requesting**...*"